# Why am I getting this error when in the documentation it says to use it?

Tags: python, discord.py

The problem I am having is that when I try to use the command it gives me the error, TypeError: Embed.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value'. It cites line 34 as the issue, does anyone know why this is happening?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message)
    if "!sell" in message.content:
        tip = random.randrange(1, 500)
        k = f"| {message.author.name} "
        val = random.randrange(1000, 5000)
        # open entire file for reading and writing
        with open("income.json", "r+") as f:
            incomes = json.load(f)


        # Either add the value to the user's balance
        # or, if they don't exist yet, create the entry
        # with the val
            try:
                incomes[k] += val + tip
            except KeyError:
                incomes[k] = val + tip

        # seek to beginning and rewrite file
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(incomes, f, indent=4)

        embedVar = discord.Embed(title=(message.author.name) + " Distributed", value=None, inline=False, color=0xfc3503)
        embedVar.add_field(name=('﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉'), value=(("You were tipped ")+(str(tip))+(" by the buyer")), inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name=('﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉﹉'), value=(f"You Earned {val} Dollars from distributing"))
```

I have tried changing the keyword value to other ones like description and have also tried changing value to = none but none of this worked.

Comment: You're trying to pass the arguments of the `add_field` method to the constructor..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official documentation doesn't include `value` as a valid parameter

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed

`class discord.Embed(*, colour=None, color=None, title=None, type='rich', url=None, description=None, timestamp=None)`

You are probably reading outdated documentation somewhere.

Comment: Now it is saying I cant use inline=False but it says that I can in the documentation. 

add_field(*, name, value, inline=True)

Comment: @Darrel.  `value` and `inline` are parameters for the `add_field()` method of an instance of the `Embed` class, but are not valid parameters for the `Embed` constructor.
Remove them from the parameter list where you create `embedVar = discoard.Embed(...)`